# Accessing jQuery AJAX Properties within ajaxStart and ajaxStop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on a project that has over 40 ajax webservice calls. I want add a few debugging options to my project. One of which is a timing method. I have already created my Timer class/object in Javascript.

I need help determining which ajax function is current running. I have implemented the `.ajaxStart` and `.ajaxStop` listeners and would like to retrieve information pertaining to the current ajax call within these function.

Is there a way to perhaps access the requested url or anything to help identify which ajax call is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [prefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/) to access the native ajax object which would give much better debug info.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, I implemented and tested your suggestion and it worked exactly as needed.